# postgresql batch select query should still return row

Tags: php, postgresql

So I have many SQL Query (could be more than 1000 query) in my PHP application, each query differentiate by its id and date like bellow:

```
SELECT dataid, date_input, value FROM app_inputdata WHERE date_input='2013-03-10' AND dataid='2337'
```

the queries take so long to complete obviously, so I am trying to batch it. how to do this, and also if a query doesnt match any row it should still return a row with `-` as `value` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a single query like this:

```
SELECT dataid, date_input, value 
FROM app_inputdata 
WHERE 
    (date_input='2013-03-10' AND dataid='2337') 
    OR (date_input='...' AND dataid='..') 
    OR (...) -- and so on
```

Getting rows that don't exist is going to make your query more complicated. I recommend doing it on PHP side. But if you insist, this is how you can get `-` as value for rows that don't exist:

```
SELECT data.date_input, data.dataid, COALESCE(app_inputdata.value, '-') as value
FROM (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[2337, 2338, ...]) as dataid, unnest(ARRAY['2013-03-10', '2013-03-11', ...]::date[]) as date_input) as data
LEFT JOIN app_inputdata ON app_inputdata.date_input = data.date_input AND app_inputdata.dataid = data.dataid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a lot (say hundreds or thousands) of `date_input` and `dataid` pairs and should check them against `app_inputdata` table, the efficient way of doing this will be first upload these pairs into temporary table and then do the single select.

The code, creating temporary table:

```
create table pg_temp.input_filter(date_input date, dataid int);
```

inserting date_input and dataid pairs:

```
insert into pg_temp.input_filter values (?,?);
```

and then select the data you need:

```
select f.date_input, f.dataid,coalesce(d.value,'-') as value
from pg_temp.input_filter f
left join app_inputdata d on d.date_input=f.date_input and d.dataid=f.dataid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement, I was thinking that maybe we can use function, creating an sql function which accepts an array of the parameters, for your case, maybe 2 kinds - "date_input" and "dataid", in the function, we can loop all parameters and save all returned result in another array, I tried in my project, but haven't do the performance comparison.

Thanks,

Johnny